# Keycloak with external identity provider - No access_token from server

Tags: spring-boot, jwt, keycloak

I'm using spring boot app as a external identity provider. when authenticate user by spring app it returns access token and refresh token.

But in keycloak it returns and error "No access_token from server"

```
[org.keycloak.broker.oidc.AbstractOAuth2IdentityProvider] (default task-47) Failed to make identity provider oauth callback: org.keycloak.broker.provider.IdentityBrokerException: No access_token from server.
at org.keycloak.broker.oidc.OIDCIdentityProvider.verifyAccessToken(OIDCIdentityProvider.java:482)
at org.keycloak.broker.oidc.OIDCIdentityProvider.getFederatedIdentity(OIDCIdentityProvider.java:350)
at org.keycloak.broker.oidc.AbstractOAuth2IdentityProvider$Endpoint.authResponse(AbstractOAuth2IdentityProvider.java:420)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:138)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.internalInvokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:517)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTargetAfterFilter(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:406)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.lambda$invokeOnTarget$0(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:370)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:355)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:372)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:344)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocatorInvoker.invokeOnTargetObject(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:137)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocatorInvoker.invoke(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:106)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocatorInvoker.invokeOnTargetObject(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:132)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocatorInvoker.invoke(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:100)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:440)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$invoke$4(SynchronousDispatcher.java:229)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$preprocess$0(SynchronousDispatcher.java:135)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:355)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.preprocess(SynchronousDispatcher.java:138)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:215)
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:227)
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56)
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:51)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:791)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
at org.keycloak.services.filters.KeycloakSessionServletFilter.doFilter(KeycloakSessionServletFilter.java:90)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:132)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:364)
at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:830)
at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

i cannot figure out that is it a configuration issue or token related issue?

Here is the generated JWT from spring boot app when authenticate the user.

```
eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJleHAiOjE1NzUwNjUyMTUsInVzZXJfbmFtZSI6ImFkbWluIiwiYXV0aG9yaXRpZXMiOlsiUk9MRV9BRE1JTiJdLCJqdGkiOiJjMjkxZTc1NC02ZmViLTRmYzAtOWFlNC1iYzUyYWU1NzcwZjQiLCJjbGllbnRfaWQiOiJSMmRweFEzdlBydGZnRjcyIiwic2NvcGUiOlsib3BlbmlkIl19.cbA4kZU3lxe3-qNVVo1nkYIw2-0N4xmC5ZfFYFK89ZV-mrey5sgFDbZKSQ97_V1jl-K1syys1TRhS9nCCvR3vszxAA7-PYXxL0JamEZmgzXX1AYD7VmreMJivak8XEvvQ4qmRbmLnE6iO5hue8-sEDfmQ0jpWIW7rmmnUkEgiqnvQYxDdlWNEPj2qYfekSSj-zXSe1R2PMO_itEghgkFYuJLp2kd5KM6brp5xU6ICgrtogH8km6hoNxSUOOUgZHqX418mDMx-IL9xEefJBMYInnACUFxpDEK0MqpVBpbnRVbbwSIqIQRrp34alajMMtbAbESFv4mmaZrJKccHVngWQ
```

Comment: Are you working in `https` or `http` if `https` did you imported the certificates

Comment: thank you for replying. Im using https. what are the certificates?

Comment: In that case you have to add certificate of your whatever identity provider you are using ,In our case it's ADFS so we have to add certificate of ADFS.

Answer (score 2):

I was getting a similar error with the latest version of Keycloak and, after seeing a similar post on the mailing list, I decided to re-enter the client secret (via the keycloak admin console) and that fixed my issue.

Comment: This fixed our Google login as well:  "Failed to make identity provider oauth callback". A bug as no changes was done at the time?

Answer (score 1):

This project contains OpenID Connect implementation in Java, It's also in spring, you can look in to it for more information.

*https://github.com/mitreid-connect/OpenID-Connect-Java-Spring-Server*

Could be due to issue with openID flow.